# Re-sizing an array with a loop

Tags: c++, arrays, memory-management, memory-leaks, allocation

I am trying to re-size my array when calling grow() if my current array is to small to continue adding values to the front or back.

```
void Vector::grow(void)
{
    // Double the capacity
  capacity_ = (capacity_) ? capacity_ * 2 : 1;

  int *temp = new int[capacity_];

  for(unsigned int i = 0; i < size_; i++)
    temp[i] = array_[i];

  array_ = temp;
  ++allocs_;
}
```

The array_ is part of the private variables in the class .h file

```
private:
  int *array_;        // The dynamically allocated array
  unsigned size_;     // The number of elements in the array
  unsigned capacity_; // The allocated size of the array
  unsigned allocs_;   // Number of allocations (resizes)
```

I am getting some problems where I am leaking memory according to Valgrind:
Invalid read of size 4
Address 0x59ff044 is 0 bytes after a block of size 4 alloc'd

Comment: What is the point of: `capacity_ = (capacity_) ? capacity_ * 2 : 1`? Also, use `std::vector` maybe? It would at least fix the memory leak present in your implementation (since you never delete the old array).

Comment: @sircodesalot if `capacity_` isn't zero, double it, else set it to 1

Comment: It looks like the assignment is to basically implement ones own vector, hence the implementation of a dynamic array (and why the class is called `Vector`)

Comment: Also, where do you free the old memory?

Comment: I have another function called clear that clears the allocated array_ when called, also the destructor frees array_. Aruisdante, your assumption is correct, the assignment is to make a vector with a couple linked list operations. That is why std::vector is not allowed and memcopy or realloc is not allowed.

Comment: "also the destructor frees array_" And should we assume you properly coded compliance with [The Rule Of Three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)) ? Because if you didn't, and *anywhere* in your program a `Vector` is ever value-copied, you'll wind up double-freeing and invoking *undefined behavior*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you never free the old memory.

```
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < size_; i++)
   temp[i] = array_[i];

array_ = temp;
```

should be:

```
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < size_; i++){
    temp[i] = array_[i];
}

delete[] array_;
array_ = temp;
```

You could also likely use `memcopy` instead of the for-loop.

Comment: I would use memcopy if I was allowed but the only way I can do make this specific function is by any loop

Comment: This fixed my problem, thank you! I swear I tried delete[] array_ I guess I forgot to test it with Valgrind.

Comment: Glad it worked out. Please accept the answer if it fixed your problem (press the little checkbox next to it)

Answer (score 0):

If you allocate memory you have to free it, or it will leak.

```
int *temp = new int[capacity_];

for(unsigned int i = 0; i < size_; i++)
    temp[i] = array_[i];

delete [] array_;  // this leaks if you don't free it.

array_ = temp;
++allocs_;
```